# Dynamic or responsive HTML table

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-table

I have a huge table (6 x 10) which will only hold logo images with varying sizes of 250x60 to smallest size of 80x60

This is my HTML code, I need a way to break it into a longer but more narrow table when viewed on a phone or a tablet. Can you offer me lead so that I can dig my way through it :) I am using WordPress and the theme is responsive so the only part that will need attention is this table for now.

Can I do this with pure CSS or should I use jQuery to change table 3x20 version? I googled responsive HTML table but got only tables with numbers :(

Or maybe leave tables and use div 's instead?

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#336633" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Leave tables and use `div`s instead. Float them.

Comment: @godfrzero thank for the idea. So I create 60 divs and float them? Every div will have image, but how to maintani 6 items in normal size and 3 items in small sizes?

Comment: Don't float the individual `div`s, create a wrapper that has 3 `div`s and float the wrappers. This way you'll get multiples of 3 per row, and the groups will jump down automatically.

Answer (score 2):

DIVs may or may not work, but this can be done with CSS and media queries.

```
@media (max-width:450px) {
   tr { display: inline; }
   td { display:block; width:30%; float:left;}
}
```

DIVs may be the better solution, but I wanted to put this as an alternative... you can restructure tables using pure CSS for a responsive design.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruhnq/

Comment: +1 for the original solution, but doesn't this [break under certain conditions](http://imgur.com/nbIz55W) based on the number of elements per row? Not sure if this edge case applies to the OPs case, but just putting it out there.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of the broken one? I'll keep tinkering around... this is a good thought exercise if nothing else.

Comment: The break can be reproduced in the original fiddle itself, just try resizing the output frame to 100% width and back again a couple times. I've actually been trying to figure out why it's breaking as well :P

Comment: Ah, I see... if only breaks when you resize a couple times. Probably not something most users will ever do, but still not great. Setting the `table` as `display:inline` seems to have resolved that. http://jsfiddle.net/ruhnq/2/

Comment: Hm, interesting. I still don't completely understand why it broke, or how it gets fixed by this. I guess I'll keep playing around with it when I get time and post if I figure it out :D

Comment: @TimWasson your solution works good on Chrome but not on IE and FF. I guess something is hitting the wall because of other css. This is the link, http://bit.ly/1bHB5Gp Change table with to 980px but did not go well :( any comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS:

```
.awesomeWrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

And some HTML:

```
<div class="awesomeWrapper">
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
</div>
<div class="awesomeWrapper">
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
  <div><img src="someImage" alt="Some Image"></div>
</div>
<!-- Repeat this pattern -->
```

This way, when the screen is too small to fit 6 images in one row, it'll automatically  reform into two rows with 3 images each. You can apply the same logic to your 6x10 grid, and it'll rearrange to a 3x20 on smaller screens.

Depending on the rest of your layout, you'll need to make some adjustments to makes sure only 6 elements show up on one line in the regular view.

Comment: Yes good example but when I try it images looks mixed up. Because small images takes less space then bigger one. This was the reason I thought of a HTML table idea. In div 's never managed to give the same look and feel :(

Comment: Well of course, I'm assuming it's okay to add some `height` and `width` to the DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out [Footable](http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/)

Or if you are using bootstrap as a theme, you coudl simply surround your table with

```
<div class="table-responsive">
// your table HTML
</div>
```